# Getting a String from an ArrayList returns null

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of Tiles with two values; an int and a String.

I need to get both values, so while I was writing the code I decided to make sure it was working:

```
private void setIcons()
    {
        ArrayList<Tiles> tiles = new ArrayList<>();
        tiles = game.getTiles(0);
        Tiles i = tiles.get(0);
        String s = i.returnTileName();
        System.out.println(i.returnTileName() +" ," +i.returnTileNumber());
    }
```

This is my Tiles class which has subclasses:

```
public class Tiles
{
    int number;
    String name;

    public Tiles()
    {

    }

    public String returnTileName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public int returnTileNumber()
    {
        return number;
    }
}
```

'Tiles' has several subclasses, all structured almost the same:

```
public class Bamboo extends Tiles
{
    int number;
    String name;
    public Bamboo(int number, String name)
    {
        this.number = number;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

When I run it, the String is returned as 'null' and my int is returned as '0', when they clearly have values, as the image below will show.

http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/6154/emx4.jpg

The method I call in setIcons() :

```
 public ArrayList getTiles(int playerX)
    {
        ArrayList<Tiles> tiles = new ArrayList<>();
        Player pl = player.get(playerX);
        tiles = pl.playerTiles;
        return tiles;
    }
```

The 'Game' class has two ArrayLists in it, 'tilesDeck', an ArrayList of Tiles and 'player',   an ArrayList of a class Player.

Here's my game class. Didn't know it had a scroll feature before now.

```
public class Game
{
    ArrayList<Tiles> tilesDeck = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Player> player = new ArrayList<>();

    public Game()
    {
        addTile("Bamboo", 1);
        addTile("Bamboo", 2);
        addTile("Bamboo", 3);
        addTile("Bamboo", 4);
        addTile("Bamboo", 5);
        addTile("Bamboo", 6);
        addTile("Bamboo", 7);
        addTile("Bamboo", 8);
        addTile("Bamboo", 9);

        addTile("Circles", 1);
        addTile("Circles", 2);
        addTile("Circles", 3);
        addTile("Circles", 4);
        addTile("Circles", 5);
        addTile("Circles", 6);
        addTile("Circles", 7);
        addTile("Circles", 8);
        addTile("Circles", 9);

        addTile("Characters", 1);
        addTile("Characters", 2);
        addTile("Characters", 3);
        addTile("Characters", 4);
        addTile("Characters", 5);
        addTile("Characters", 6);
        addTile("Characters", 7);
        addTile("Characters", 8);
        addTile("Characters", 9);

        addTile("Dragons", 1);
        addTile("Winds", 1);

        Collections.shuffle(tilesDeck);
        player.add(new Player("Player 1"));
        player.add(new Player("Player 2"));
        player.add(new Player("Player 3"));
        player.add(new Player("Player 4"));

        startTiles();
    }

    private void addTile(String name, int number)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        if (name.contains("Bamboo"))
        {
            while (counter < 4)
            {
                tilesDeck.add(new Bamboo(number, name));
                counter++;
            }
        }

        if (name.contains("Circles"))
        {
             while (counter < 4)
            {
                tilesDeck.add(new Circles(number, name));
                counter++;
            }
        }

        if (name.contains("Characters"))
        {
             while (counter < 4)
            {
                tilesDeck.add(new Characters(number, name));
                counter++;
            }
        }

        if (name.contains("Winds"))
        {
             while (counter < 4)
            {
                tilesDeck.add(new Winds("East"));
                tilesDeck.add(new Winds("South"));
                tilesDeck.add(new Winds("West"));
                tilesDeck.add(new Winds("North"));
                counter++;
            }
        }

        if (name.contains("Dragons"))
        {
             while (counter < 4)
            {
                tilesDeck.add(new Dragons("Red"));
                tilesDeck.add(new Dragons("Green"));
                tilesDeck.add(new Dragons("White"));
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }

    private void startTiles()
    {
        int playerCounter = 0;

        while (playerCounter < 4)
        {
            Player pl = player.get(playerCounter);
            int counter = 0;
            while (counter <13)
            {
                pl.playerTiles.add(tilesDeck.get(0));
                tilesDeck.remove(0);
                counter++;
            }
            playerCounter++;
        }
    }

    public ArrayList getTiles(int playerX)
    {
        ArrayList<Tiles> tiles = new ArrayList<>();
        Player pl = player.get(playerX);
        tiles = pl.playerTiles;
        return tiles;
    }
}
```

Comment: They clearly don't have values, as you see when you run the program.

Comment: Please add more information about `game` and the `game.getTiles(0)` instruction

Comment: I don't think there's enough code here for us to spot the bug.

Comment: The screenshot indicates that `i` is an instance of a subclass of `Tiles`. If so, is the method overridden in it? It might be helpful to see its source.

Comment: Added some code from one of the subclasses.

Comment: I figured I should spar you looking through my Game class, as most of it is slightly repetitive... I'll look through and see if I can find the most important parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your subclasses are creating duplicate number and name variables:

```
public class Bamboo extends Tiles
{
    int number; // <-- remove this
    String name; // <-- and this
    public Bamboo(int number, String name)
    {
        this.number = number;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Class Bamboo is initializing the duplicate number and name variables, but the `returnTileName()` and `returnTileNumber()` methods are returning the uninitialized variables from the Tiles superclass.

Comment: Thank you! This solved it. If I had enough 'reputation', I'd upvote your reply.

Again, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Tiles()
{

}
```

initialize your variables inside there.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your variables with some default value to avoid getting null values.

```
public class Tiles
{
// assign your default values
int number = 1;           
String name = "default name";

public Tiles()
{

}

public String returnTileName()
{
    return name;
}

public int returnTileNumber()
{
    return number;
}
}
```

Comment: When I change my code to this, it returns '1' and "default name".

Comment: yes thats because you have initialized the variables with these values. Change it to whatever you want them to be.

Comment: They should get changed in their subclasses? or have I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 0):

You must initialise your variables in your constructor

Comment: I have them initialized in my subclasses... is that good enough?
thanks for replying.